# Boot slow on freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, uefi, startup

My dual boot (win10/ubuntu20.04) laptop (lenovo t14s gen1) "completely" crashed a couple of days ago.

**What's up:** Experiencing 2min+ boot times (48s firmware, 1min loader) into a freshly installed single ubuntu 22.04 (no dual boot anymore) and while using it, UEFI responds very slowly (feels like 1-2 fps, if at all). `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` below:

```
Startup finished in 48.069s (firmware) + 1min 3.309s (loader) + 7.991s (kernel) +
8.290s (userspace) = 2min 7.660s 
graphical.target reached after 8.283s in userspace

graphical.target @8.283s
└─multi-user.target @8.283s
  └─kerneloops.service @8.272s +9ms
    └─network-online.target @8.270s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @2.013s +6.256s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.966s +42ms
          └─dbus.service @1.964s
            └─basic.target @1.956s
              └─sockets.target @1.956s
                └─snapd.socket @1.954s +855us
                  └─sysinit.target @1.943s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service @3.138s +6ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @558ms
                        └─system.slice @157ms
                          └─-.slice @157ms
```

**How can I get a regular boot time back again and how can I make that UEFI operates on a normal responsive level again?**

**What happened:** I was exclusively using ubuntu 20.04 but had a dual boot w/ win10, regularly running the system updates as recommended by ubuntu. (I used win10 twice on this machine as far as I can remember. The last time over a year ago.) I think after a system update incl. firmware was deployed a couple of days ago my system started acting weird. Namely, very long boot times. Then yesterday after I tried to resume my laptop from suspension it wouldn't respond anymore and the display showed many pretty colors but nothing humanly understandable. After forcing power-off it would only start win10. It didn't show the typical bootloader options at all. I looked into the boot options on system startup using F12 and found no ubuntu entry at all (also not when in UEFI boot menu). I used a usblive stick w/ ubuntu 22.04 and boot-repair but it produced an error:

```
NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr).
```

The startup of the system was still very slow. Also, when in UEFI, the navigation was soooo slow (it felt like only 1-2 fps), very slow responding on key inputs. I also want to add, when booting into win10 windows behaved quite responsive and not slow at all.

Then I was impatient, since I need the laptop for work, and freshly installed ubuntu 22.04 (w/ no dual boot anymore) alongside the most urgent software (I regularly operate w/ git and data on a cloud so I barely had any data loss on reinstalling ubuntu). System startup is still slow (see `systemd-analyze` output above). Now I am lost. I don't understand why startup of `firmware` and `loader` (whatever the latter is) takes this much time. My gut feeling tells me some hardware drivers might be broken or UEFI is damaged in some way.

I am willing to do anything (again, complete reinstall, down/upgrading drivers/UEFI) as long as I get a normally operating machine again. Thx in advance :).

**Update: Solved** after a couple of Ubuntu updates.